# Print a number dependent on how many of X there are

Tags: php

Below, I want `$slideNumber` to be determined by the number of slides there are. I've attempted to create a variable in the Slide section and have it increase by 1 for each new slide. Then I attempted to plug that into:

`<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>">`

But nothing is outputting. It just outputs the word `slide` for the `id`. What can I do to fix this?

To clarify, if there are five slides, there should be five `inputs` printing like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5">
```

What can I do to fix this?

```
<!-- Slider Setup -->
<?php if( have_rows('slides') ):
    while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row();

?>

    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>">

<?php endwhile;endif; ?>

<!-- Slide -->
<?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>

    <div id="slides">
        <div id="overflow">
            <div class="inner">

                <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): 

                $slideNumber = 1;
                while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row(); 

                    $slideNumber++;
                    $slideImage = get_sub_field('slide_image');

                ?>

                    <article>
                        <img src="<?php echo $slideImage; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    </article>

                <?php endwhile;endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #inner -->
        </div><!-- #overflow -->
    </div><!-- #slides -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why did you accept the answer to your last question then, if copy and pasting it doesn't work?

Comment: I asked that question wrong. I realized it had to depend on the number of slides. So I opened up a new question because I didn't want to confuse anyone. Is that against the rules? Plus, I gave that guy the check because technically he did answer my question.

Comment: Leaving your last question around with a misleading title and a completely different answer isn't really helpful to future readers. You're rescoping the topic and asking for iterative code rewriting. Still insufficient information on where `have_rows()` originates from. And you seemingly didn't even bother with enabling `error_reporting`.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because The question has too many unknows in it. No idea what `have_row(), the_row(), get_sub_field()` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to use `$slideNumber` variable when it's not even defined, here:

```
<!-- Slider Setup -->
<?php if( have_rows('slides') ):
    while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row();

?>

    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>">
    <!-- You're using $slideNumber here - but it's not defined or incremented -->

<?php endwhile;endif; ?>
```

Instead, you define and increment this property here:

```
        <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): 

        $slideNumber = 1; // you define it here
        while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row(); 

            $slideNumber++; // you increment it for every slide
            $slideImage = get_sub_field('slide_image');

        ?>

            <article> <!-- but you actually don't use it -->
                <img src="<?php echo $slideImage; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            </article>

        <?php endwhile;endif; ?>
```

Please try this code instead:

```
<!-- Slider Setup -->
<?php if( have_rows('slides') ):
    $slideNumber = 1; // defined
    while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row();

?>
    <!-- Has to output something for id attribute, at least "slide1" -->
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide<?php echo $slideNumber; ?>">

<?php
$slideNumber++; // incremented
endwhile;
endif;
?>

<!-- Slide -->
<?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>

    <div id="slides">
        <div id="overflow">
            <div class="inner">

                <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): 
                while ( have_rows('slides') ) : the_row(); 
                    $slideImage = get_sub_field('slide_image');

                ?>

                    <article>
                        <img src="<?php echo $slideImage; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    </article>

                <?php endwhile;endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #inner -->
        </div><!-- #overflow -->
    </div><!-- #slides -->

<?php endif; ?>
```